# Let $f:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ and $\vec{u}\mapsto \vec{u}\times (1,2,3)$. Show that $f$ is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ and $\vec{u}\mapsto \vec{u}\times (1,2,3)$.

- Show that $f$ is linear.
- Let $A$ be the image matrix of $f.$ Determine ker$(A),$ col$(A)$, nulldim$(A)$ and rank$(A).$

---

The concept of linearity is defined as: *The function* $f:N\rightarrow M$ *is linear if*

$$ (1) \quad \ \ \left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    f(x'+x'') & = & f(x')+f(x''), \quad &\forall (x',x'')\in N \\
    f(\lambda x) & = & \lambda f(x), \quad &\forall \lambda\in\mathbb{R}, \ x\in N \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

So how can I show that the given $f$ in the problem satisfies $(1)?$ What my function is saying is that $f$ takes the vector $\vec{u}$ and maps it onto $\vec{u}\times(1,2,3)$, or $f(\vec{u})=\vec{u}\times (1,2,3).$

Let, for simplicity, $\vec{v}=(1,2,3)$. Say that we have another vector $\vec{w}$ such that $f(\vec{w}+(\vec{u}\times\vec{v})),$ Now I need to show that this function is equal to $f(\vec{w})+f(\vec{u}\times\vec{v}),$ here im stuck. Am I making this harder than it really is?

Comment: What do you know about the cross-product?

Comment: Shouldn't it say $f(\vec{u}) = \vec{u}\times(1,2,3)$ in stead of $f(\vec{u}\times(1,2,3)) = \vec{u}$?

Comment: The crossproduct of two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ is $|u|v|\sin{\theta}$, where theta is the angle between them. This product generates a vector orthogonal to the plane that is spanned by$\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.

Comment: @Yannik Yes, edited, thanks.

Comment: @Parseval Are you not aware of that fact that $\vec u\times(\vec v+\vec w)=\vec u\times\vec v+\vec u\times\vec w$ and that $\vec u\times(\lambda\vec v)=\lambda\vec u\times\vec v$?

Comment: Yes I am. I just don't see how that is applicable here. I have $(\vec{u} \times \vec{v}) + \vec{w}$ and not $\vec{u} \times (\vec{v}+\vec{w}).$

Comment: Actually, you should only show that $f(\vec{u} + \vec{w}) = (\vec{u} + \vec{w})\times \vec{v} = \vec{u}\times \vec{v} + \vec{w}\times\vec{v} = f(\vec{v}) + f(\vec{w})$.

Comment: @Yannik - that's only the first row in (1), i have to show the second too.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$f(\vec{u}) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 3 & -2 \\ -3 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\vec{u} = A\vec{u}$$

Now it should be evident that $f$ is linear:

$$f(\lambda \vec{u} + \mu \vec{v}) = A(\lambda \vec{u} + \mu \vec{v}) = \lambda\, A\vec{u} + \mu \,A\vec{v} = \lambda f(\vec{u}) + \mu f(\vec{v})$$

Comment: How did you get that matrix?

Comment: @Parseval Let $\vec{u} = (u_x,u_y,u_z)$. We have $$\vec{u}\times (1,2,3) = (3u_y-2u_z,u_z-3u_x,2u_x-u_y)$$
Now recognize this as $A\vec{u}$.